# How to apply different icons & different text in android grid view tutorial?

Tags: android, image, gridview, text, icons

Please tell me about how to change or apply different icons with different text in the android grid view tutorial. My code is

```
public class Home extends Activity
{    
    //---the images to display---
    Integer[] imageIDs = {

    };

    GridView grid_main;

    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        grid_main = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        grid_main.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        grid_main.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
            View v, int position, long id) 
            {                
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        Context mContext;
        public static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 10;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            mContext = c;
        }

        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return 12;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item--- 
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

            View v;
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text1);
                tv.setText("Profile "+position);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image1);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bo_1);

            }
            else
            {
                v = convertView;
            }
            return v;
        }
    }    
}
```

This code is running perfectly but all the images nd text are same so i need to change it. please tell me how to do it ?
Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Much, much, much better for ImageAdapter is:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
                tv.setText(mTextsIds[position]);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
                iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            } else {
                v = (View) convertView;
            }
            return v;
        }

        // references to our images
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4
        };

        // references to our texts
        private String[] mTextsIds = {
                "Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4"
        };
    }
```

Please, note that images and texts are in variables **mThumbIds** and **mTextsIds**

The grid_item.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget44"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_x="201px"
    android:layout_y="165px"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/icon_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColorHighlight="#656565"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two most important lines are these four:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text1);
tv.setText("Profile "+position);
ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image1);

if (position == 0) {
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bo_1);
} else if (position == 1) {
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bo_2);
}
```

In the first line you get the TextView from the XMLlayout file. Afterwards you set the text of this TextView to "Profile " and a number. In third line your initializing the ImageView. After that you're using the image called bo1 in that ImageView. So all you have to do is to add another text in the second line and change the image you're referring in the fourth line.

Comment: No It's Not working like the way you suggested. By implementing your logic i.e., adding another text in the second line and changing the image reference in the fourth line it changes the image of all the 12 icons as i mentioned in the getcount method to the one i have referenced it. Actually i want 12 different icons with 12 different text and if i add these four lines again it increases the no. of icons and if i make the count to 1 then its fine but the icons are displaying vertically onlyn because of the linear layout in xml. Please help me out it's so urgent !

Comment: By the way Thx for helping me out !

Comment: Ah you don't want just to change the image but various images... Then I would add a switch statement as I added in my answer.

Comment: @Roflcoptr Can u Please elaborate your logic of using switch statement  so that i can apply it to my code !

Comment: @Roflcoptr Thank u sir ! Thanks a lot !! It works for me m really glad to meet u here !! ok and now if i want to make them clickable what would i need to do...??

Comment: Now you would have to add a ClickListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Comment: Thx a lot for your precious time to help me out !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

            View v;
            ImageView iv = null;
            TextView tv = null;
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text1);
                tv.setText("Profile "+position);
                iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image1);


            }
            else
            {
                v = convertView;
            }
            iv.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            return v;
        }
```

Thanks
Deepak